# Enlist if not None

Tags: python

Is there a standard library function equivalent to the following?

```py
def enlist_if_not_none(n):
    if n: return [n]
    return []
```

Here is a usage example:

```
for cluster_node in clients_list + enlist_if_not_none(backup_server):
    # do something, backup_server is not in the list if it's None.
```

Comment: Whats the problem with the function that you defined? Why can't you continue the loop if `cluster_node` is none?

Comment: No there isn't. Also it should be `if n is not None: return [n]` ...otherwise if `n` was empty list `[]` you would end up with `[[]]`

Comment: @Anentropic Agreed. In my context, I know that the argument is either a node object or None.

Comment: What happens inside the loop? Wouldn't it be easier to just do `clients_list + [backup_server]` and handle the `None` case inside the loop? What happens if there are `None`s inside `clients_list`?

Comment: @Tomerikoo You'd be right if this was possible. In my context it isn't.

Comment: I'm curious to see what is your context. It's hard for me to imagine how that would not be possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for `filter()` or the ternary operator `A if CONDITION else B`

```py
cluster_node in clients_list + list(filter(None, [backup_server]))
cluster_node in filter(None, clients_list + [backup_server])
```

```py
cluster_node in clients_list + ([backup_server] if backup_server is not None else []):
```

---

Note that `filter(None, _)` will remove any Falsey values (not just `None`, akin to `if _:` vs `if _ is not None`) unless you provide a function or lambda which explicitly checks against `None`

Behavior Example

```py
>>> [1] + list(filter(None, [None]))
[1]
>>> [1] + list(filter(None, [2]))
[1, 2]
```

Include `0` (and `False` et al.)

```py
>>> [1] + list(filter(None, [0]))  # Falsey 0 filtered
[1]
>>> [1] + list(filter(lambda x: x is not None, [0]))
[1, 0]
>>> [1] + list(filter(lambda x: x is not None, [None]))
[1]
```

Comment: you're right! it must also explicitly be made a list to be append/extend-able on `clients_list` (though tbh some `itertools.chain*` is probably a nicer shape)

Comment: Right! I forgot that `filter` can be used without `lambda`. This way it is not too bulky to be inlined. Great!

Comment: @AlwaysLearning it's quite useful! that said, I'd probably prefer the second using the ternary for clarity if not brevity or `filter()` everything to avoid an intermediate list (at the expense of checking each value .. though it's also shorter! .. added example)

Comment: Since in my context `clients_list` cannot contain `None`, I feel that applying `filter` to everything is a bit misleading.